# Function template return type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I have some class `C` with `const` and non-`const` getters for some generic type `Node`:

```
template <typename NodeType>
class CParent{};

class Node {};

class C : public CParent<Node> {
    Node&       getNode(Index i);
    const Node& getNode(Index i) const;
};
```

Now I want to create an alias function that call `getNode` for an object of class `C`:

```
template <class CType>
NodeType& AliasGetNode(CType* cobject);
```

But how do I deduce `NodeType`? i.e., if I call `AliasGetNode<const C>(c)` and `AliasGetNode<C>(c)`, `NodeType`should be respectively `const Node&`and `Node&`.

How can I do this?

I tried the `result_of` and `decltype` approaches but have not been successful.

Comment: `I tried the result_of and decltype approaches but have not been successful.` You should post _what_ you tried, and what happened. Just making vague allusions to things and saying they didn't work is not useful. I mean, I'm guessing you just got 49 screenfuls of template errors, but it would be nice to be sure!

Comment: @underscore_d for sure. However in this case, since I expected the solution to be simple, I tried to avoid the 49 screenfuls of clutter. Plus, there are lots of specific questions on the `result_of` and `decltype` topic that do not address my problem specifically and I would get a wrong "duplicated" question flag

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend the:

```
template <class CType>
auto AliasGetNode(CType& cobject) -> decltype(cobject.getNode(0))
{
    return cobject.getNode(0);
}
```

This should fairly work since c++11

Comment: Selected this as answer for not using C++14, although it seems like a workaround

Comment: Why does not using C++14 make this more correct? If anything, that makes it worse, and you did tag `c++14` in your question.

Answer (score 21):

Let the compiler deduce the return type (as of C++14):

```
template <class CType>
decltype(auto) AliasGetNode(CType& cobject)
{
    return cobject.getNode(0);
}
```

Comment: Nice! in c++11 you could also do `auto AliasGetNode(CType& cobject) -> decltype(cobject.getNode(0))`

Comment: @W.F. For c++14 you mean. And return type deduction on `decltype(auto)` will do even better :)

Comment: @StoryTeller I actually mean for both standards:)

Comment: They both behave the same way. Both return a copy if `decltype(auto)` doesn't resolve to a reference type. Therefore `auto &` is more appropriate for the OP.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - Is it? If `getNode()` is changed to return by value, than `auto&` will fail to compile.

Comment: @Potatoswatter why `decltype(auto)` shouldn't resolve to reference?

Comment: @StoryTeller That sounds like a bug stopped in its tracks before reaching the unit tests.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - And a hassle. `decltype(auto)` will deduce a reference type in the OP's case. And it will deduce `Node` correctly if the OP needs to return by value instead. It's not an abuse. The OP wants to return exactly the declared type of `getNode()`. `decltype(auto)` is the proper deduction.

Comment: @W.F. The purpose of `decltype(auto)` is to be ambiguous about returning by reference or by value. It's used when either will do, but the function should not constrain how its value is returned.

Comment: @Potatoswatter But if `getNode()` returns a copy `AliasGetNode()` shouldn't be able to return reference to that copy or at least it should warn about it...

Comment: @StoryTeller The goal is to reduce the overall amount of work for the programmer, not to prevent the compiler from ever complaining about anything. Interfaces should be self-documenting. This looks like an accessor into a data structure, which would not be working properly if it copied the desired `Node`.

Comment: @W.F. C++ already prevents returning a non-`const` reference to a temporary and I hear that a rule disallowing the `const` case is on the way as well.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - Do you have a reference for that proposal? Sounds like an interesting read.

Comment: @StoryTeller I do not. There is [P0066](http://wg21.link/P0066) which I wrote, but simply forbidding returning a prvalue by reference doesn't require any of its proposed extensions.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: C++ does not prevent returning a reference to a temporary.  Consider if the body of the function were changed to `return CType{}.getNode(0);`

Comment: @BenVoigt Catching *that* would require P0066. It would still be a dangling return with `decltype(auto)`. I'm not sure what you think I said…

Answer (score 6):

Define a simple helper trait, which will add/remove `const` from a type based on whether another type is `const`:

```
template <class Src, class Dst>
using copy_const = typename std::conditional<
  std::is_const<Src>::value,
  const Dst,
  typename std::remove_const<Dst>::type
>::type;
```

And use it:

```
template <class CType>
copy_const<CType, NodeType>& AliasGetNode(CType* cobject);
```

Answer (score 5):

Since C++14 the return type of a function may be deduced by the compiler:

```
template<typename CType>
decltype(auto) AliasGetNode(CType& cobject) {
    return cobject.getNode();
}
```

When you call `AliasGetNode` on the object of type `Node`, `CType` is deduced to `Node`. But if you call `AliasGetNode` on the object of type `const Node`, `CType` is deduced to `const Node`.

It is important to make return type of `AliasGetNode` as `decltype(auto)`, otherwise you will miss a reference and constness for the returned type.

Comment: `decltype(auto)` does not guarantee a reference return type. `auto &` and `auto const &` do.

Comment: @Potatoswatter why not? Can you explain?

Answer (score 3):

You should write two alias functions, one for non-const instance and the other for const instance:

```
template <class CType>
const NodeType& AliasGetNode(const CType* cobject) const;  // for const instance. 
// The function must be const since the only difference between return type will cause redefinition error.

template <class CType>
NodeType& AliasGetNode(CType* cobject);  // for non-const instance
```

The instances declared const will call the const functions if there are overload functions. Of course, non-const instances will call the non-const version of the overload function. For example:

```
class Aclass {
    public:
       string test() { return "calling non-const function"; }
       string test() const { return "calling const function"; }
};

int main() {
    Aclass a;
    const Aclass b;

    cout << a.test() << endl;
    cout << b.test() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result will be:

```
calling non-const function
calling const function
```